# what is firebase storage transferred and operations?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

i'm calculating costs of using firebase as my app backend solution and i need to know in details what does GB transferred and Operations mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the pricing estimator.  It will be more clear if you look at the pricing closer to the at the top of the page for storage.  It will become clear that "transferred" is the same thing as downloads, since that's the only type of transfer that's quoted a price.  And operations are broken down into individual  numbers of uploads and downloads.

On that page, in general, you should first use the prices quotes at the top of the page to understand billing structure, then once you understand that, use the pricing estimator at the bottom.

Comment: i've already read it at the top but it was not clear till you made it clear for me, so thank you